# Multiple emails from Jenkins

Tags: email, groovy, jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job that generates variable number and types of reports each time it runs. Depending on the type of report generated (I can figure that out from the filename), I have to send it to specific email addresses.

I am able to get it working for some combinations by using "Editable Email Notification" and "Pre-send Script".

But, since these combinations are over 50 in number, I do not want to create separate "Editable Email Notification" sections for each of these. Is there an easy way to code up the using "Pre-send Script" or just plain "Groovy Postbuild" to send multiple emails?